# Why doesn't iptables drop 10. addresses?

Tags: iptables

I'm seeing brute force web login attempts from 10.19.0.222
My iptables contains:

```
DROP all  --  anywhere anywhere match-set manual src
```

ipset test manual 10.19.0.222 confirms the address is in the set, but I continue to see the web login attempts from that address.

My iptables/ipset configuration is working perfectly for the many others addresses in the set, but seems ineffective with this 10. address.

Why is this?

And I thought 10. was reserved for private subnets.  Why am I even seeing this address?

I have 3 interfaces:

```
eth0: inet addr:162.243.193.60  Bcast:162.243.193.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
lo: inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
tun0: inet addr:10.9.0.1  P-t-P:10.9.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
```

How can I determine which interface 10.19.0.222 came in on?

Comment: are you sure it is not _your_ address?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is from your LAN. Isn't it IP of your web server? 10.0.0.0/8 subnet is reserved for private using and is not routed on Internet at all (routers should drop packets with this IPs going to public Internet).